# In Google Sheets How do I get a sum of comma separated values in rows against an ID

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I have a table which has a list of id's against names

```
Sheet 1
A   | B
1   | Joe
12  | Dave
23  | Pete
```

I then have a table of rows which shows when a person was present at an event (through their ID)

```
Sheet 2
A       | B
boston  | 1
florida | 1,12
nyc     | 12,23
```

In the 3rd sheet for appearances, I am then looking to achieve the following

```
Sheet 3
A    | B (Appearances)
Joe  | 2
Dave | 2
Pete | 1
```

I can get this to work when just one person makes an appearance with something like `=COUNTIF(appearances!A:A, INDEX(name_db!$A$2:$A$1000, MATCH ($A11, name_db!$B$2:$B$1000, 0)))`

But as soon as I add a comma value it all goes wrong.

I've tried looking into `vLOOKUPS` and things like that but can't seem to quite figure it out

Any help on where to look would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G:G, QUERY(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(E:E, ","))<>"", "♦"&SPLIT(E:E, ","), )), "♦")), A:B, 2, 0), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 label count(Col1)''", 0), 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SUM(SPLIT(D2;","))))`